# React Native Android networking does not work

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I run a React Native app on Android emulator but found networking does not work, I run it on iOS it works fine.
Here is the simple code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const useFetch = async () => {
      try {
        console.log('fetch ...');
        let response = await fetch('https://mytestdomain.com');
        console.log(response.status);
        // let json = await response.json();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    useFetch();

    const useXMLHttpRequest = async () => {
      try {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
          if (request.readyState !== 4) {
            console.log(request.readyState);
            return;
          }

          if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log('success', request.responseText);
          } else {
            console.warn('error');
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', 'https://mytestdomain.com');
        request.send();

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    useXMLHttpRequest();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.layout}>
      <Text>React Native Android networking</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  layout: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

By call useFetch() I just see 'fetch ...' in console, even can not see response.status, and there is no error from catch.

By call useXMLHttpRequest() I see request.readyState is 1.

Thanks advance for any help

Comment: Hey, were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should give this **asynchronous** log a more explicit message to find this specific one among other logs, like :

```
console.log("RS : " + response.status);
```

I tried to reproduce your issue, and I can't, it works on my Android simulator just fine.
Would you please share your console logs ?

A workaround is to use the ***@react-native-community/netinfo*** library to determine whether you have internet access or not.

**Beware, it could be slow.**

This library provides a listener with the connection details changes. Getting the connection details can be slow... you would have to test it on real devices to determine whether this workaround is efficient or not.

Quick Demo based on your source code :

```
    [...]
    import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
    +import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
    
    export default () => {
    -  React.useEffect(() => {
    +  NetInfo.addEventListener((netInfo) => {
        const useFetch = async () => {
        try {
    -        console.log("fetch ...");
    -        let response = await fetch("https://mytestdomain.com");
    -        console.log(response.status);
    -        // let json = await response.json();
    +        // Just because there is a connection, it does not mean that internet is accessible, so test both isConnected and isInternetReachable
    +        if (netInfo.isConnected && netInfo.isInternetReachable) {
    +          console.log("fetch ...");
    +          let response = await fetch(
    +            "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch"
    +          );
    +          console.log("start 1");
    +          console.log("success 1", response.status);
    +          console.log("stop 1");
    +        } else {
    +          console.log("internet is not ready");
    +        }
        } catch (error) {
    [...]
```